# Illustrator mesh tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is a gradient mesh created in Illustrator still a vector format, I need to emboss a logo. I don't want to spend eons on the mesh only to find it is in pixel format.

Comment: Please clarify. By " I need to emboss a logo," do you mean you need to apply an emboss effect, or do you need to literally emboss a logo? Please attach an image of the logo for more helpful responses.

Comment: Clarify the outcome you need that requires the gradient to be in vector format for and you'll probably get the answer you need. For example, is it a fear that you won't be able to enlarge the finished piece later if the gradient is stored as raster information?

Answer (score 2):

Gradient meshes are vector.

They remain vector the same as any gradient will remain vector. There's no more concern over using meshes than there should be over using linear or radial gradients. The same general guidelines apply ..... *what that means is*....

Saved to a format which supports meshes, you still have a vector mesh.

- EPS (even old EPS versions like AI8) - still vector
- PDF 1.4 (Acrobat 5) or greater - still vector
- AI (pretty much any version newer than AI7) - still vector

A mesh will *not* remain a vector object in some circumstances:

- Save to PDF 1.3 (Acrobat 4) or older, including PDFX-1a
- Save to a flat file format (obviously anything raster)
- Export the file to some format for a non-Adobe application which doesn't support gradient meshes (as Adobe codes them).
- The mesh interacts with *other objects* in the artwork and must be flattened in some formats.

  - This means if you have a mesh on top of a rectangle with a blending mode applied, or use opacity on *any* of the mesh color stops, things will be flattened for output and some formats which do not support transparency. This interaction will *often* cause vector objects, not just meshes, to be flattened into embedded raster elements with vector clipping paths.

In **many** cases, using a mesh *without* using **any** blending modes or opacity settings will retain the mesh as a vector object, at least for newer file formats. The primary factor is *how* the mesh may *interact* with other objects.

In cases where the mesh may need to be flattened, it would be flattened for *output*, such as a PDF/X-1a, where it's customary to flatten many vector objects, not merely meshes. And in these instances, it's a mandatory conversion for RIPS/press, so there's little to be concerned with.

I, personally, have used standard meshes on top of, and interacting with, standard objects for many, many years and never run into any specific issues with the construction or usage. I am not one to use blending modes and transparency within Illustrator though. I tend to work as if those options aren't even available in Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Two views of a gradient which was made by using the Gradient mesh. The upper is Illustrator vector shape, the lower is rasterized to 300 pixels/inch. Both versions are seen zoomed to 4800%.

The gradient mesh stays as vector until some effect, which rasterize the gradients, is applied. For example 3D effects rasterize Gradients. The gradient mesh itself isn't a raster effect.